# All traffic forwarded by load balancer to one target

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I have an AWS Network Load Balancer with 2 EC2 instances registered as targets. The problem arising in it is that all the load is forwarded to only one of the 2 instances, which beats the whole purpose of having a load balancer.

I have checked the following things:-

1. Both the instances are healthy
2. Cross-Zonal Load Balancing is enabled

Is there any other reason why this is happening? If yes, then how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other reason why this is happening? If yes, then how to fix it

Yes. A most likely reason is that your NLB is using **different AZs** than your EC2 instances. Probably one instance is located in an AZ not enabled for the NLB.